# GWT ListBox detect when value is re-selected

Tags: gwt, listbox

I'm having a problem using a GWT listbox. I have a case where the user selects a value from a listBox, but it can become invalidated if they change data in a related field. To validate the listBox, the user has to either select a new value, or confirm their old selection by selecting the same value again. I can't figure out how to determine if they have selected the same value so that I can restyle the listBox to look validated.

The valueChanged handler only detects if a new value is selected. The clickHandler and focusHandler fire too often because they fire when the user isn't selecting a value. Any ideas?

Comment: Very bad user interface idea.

Comment: What do you mean "very bad idea". I don't have a choice in the design. Is there a better way to implement the same functionality? And I'm going to try and edit some code in, but it might not help much.

Comment: This design is very confusing even when you describe it. A user has to select the same value again?! A better option is to show a small dialog where you explain why the selection is not valid, and then ask what a user wants to do, e.g. "Do you still want to select this value?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the clickHandler with something like this :

```
     ignoreClick = true;
     lastSelection =  -1 ;
            ....
    listBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            if (!ignoreClick) {
                lastSelection = listBox.getSelectedIndex();
            }
            ignoreClick = !ignoreClick;     
        }
    });
```

I tried it and the event was only fired if you selected an item. But you should rethink your user interface , like said above.

Comment: I ended up implementing this and it works well. This was a defect I was fixing, and all the code was already in place. I wouldn't have written it so strangely in the first place, but somebody else did and I can't rewrite the whole page now. Thanks for your help!